# Laravel 5.4 whereHas query bug

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

For most tracks that code works, but for some it doesn't. 
What's wrong with my code?

```
$track = Track::where( 'id', 7 )->whereHas('rights', function ( $query ){
    $query->where( 'user_id',  1 );
})->get();
dd( $track );
```

**Output**

```
Collection {#301
  #items: []
}
```

**SQL**

```
select * from `tracks` where `id` = ? and exists (select * from `rights` where `tracks`.`id` = `rights`.`track_id` and `user_id` = ?) and `tracks`.`deleted_at` is null
```

**Database**

```
rights
---
| id | rightholder_type_id | user_id | track_id |
| -: |          -:         |   -:    |     -    |
| 29 |           1         |    1    |     7    |
```

Comment: This is very unlikely to be a bug in Laravel. What does your database record look like for `Track` #7?

Comment: `Track::find(  7 )` works fine

Comment: What's your relationship look like?

Comment: Track hasMany Right, Track belongsTo User, Right belongsTo User, Right belongsTo Track

Comment: Can you show the `tracks` table?

Comment: here is Tracks table http://icecream.me/uploads/55be0b60312c41c43e7fa0e02a10a7d2.png

Comment: @fiter are the relationships actually declared correctly? You've not posted any code on which to verify this. What are the binding values for the SQL query? If you run the full SQL query in your database console, what result do you get?

Comment: $track->rights, $right->user and etc. works fine. This query returns an empty result

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your reply. I have created a fresh install of Laravel 5.4, with models and relationships, which I believe to be identical to yours (you've not posted your full code or DB schema, so I'm guessing). I've duplicated your query and I get the expected result.

Comment: And this is my query and bindings. `select * from foo where id = ? and exists (select * from bar where foo.id = bar.foo_id and baz_id = ?) and foo.deleted_at is null` `[3,2]`

Comment: Sometimes it works, sometimes not, it depends on id of track in my case

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't really help anyone to be able to help you debug the problem. You're going to need to share your migrations, models, and sample data.